# How to find $\operatorname{tr}(Dvw^T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a read-valued diagonal matrix and $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be two vectors.  Is there some nice way to compute trace of $Dvw^T$?

I am asking this question because of some Frobenius norm optimization problem. could you help me please?

Comment: It's $w^TDv.\phantom{                 }$

Comment: @user1551, Indeed, thanks!.

Comment: look for only diagonal entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v=( v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n})$ and $w=(w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{n})$  then diagonal entries of $v w^{T}$ is $v_{1}w_{1},v_{2}w_{2},...,v_{n}w_{n}$.
Hence diagonal entries in $D v w^{T}$ is the product of respective diagonal entries in the two matrices (as $D$ is a diagonal matrix) i.e. diagonal entries of  $D v w^{T}$ are $a_{1}v_{1}w_{1},a_{2}v_{2}w_{2},...,a_{n}v_{n}w_{n}$ where $ a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ are the diagonal entries in $D$.
Hence the trace is $a_{1}v_{1}w_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}w_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n}w_{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's a useful fact that $\text{Tr}(AB) = \text{Tr}(BA)$, when both products $AB$ and $BA$ are defined. With $D, u ,v$ as given in the question, this fact implies that
$$
\text{Tr}(Dvw^T) =
\text{Tr}(w^T Dv) = w^T Dv.
$$
(The last equality follows because $w^T Dv$ is a scalar.)